# Does an entire dev team need to install Ruby in order for Sass to work on their local machines?

Tags: ruby, sass

The  UI developers touch the CSS, but given that Sass's workflow creates CSS, would any machine that displays the app (servers included?) need to have Ruby and Sass installed to view the app properly?

Or is it enough for anyone just working on the UI to have Ruby and Sass installed, in which case updating the CSS is done by a UI guy, and then the rendered file can be committed to be viewed and used by all?

Comment: Asking for recommendations of tools (like Eclipse plugins) is considered to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on StackOverflow, but your main question is a good one, so I've just edited out the off-topic part and cleaned up the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need Ruby to **compile** Sass, the app will use the CSS (in fact, you don't need Sass files on your production app).

So only the people who are susceptible to work on the UI need to have Ruby (ans Sass) installed.

*Sidenote:*
Some frameworks allow on-the-fly Sass compilation (I'm thinking to Laravel-SASS for example). In this case, everyone need to have both Ruby ans Sass installed.